# Wpf Button Click for multiple Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having an issue with the buttons in my application.
I am using Vector graphics to render each button, and when clicked i would like the button to preform a simple pinching animation to show feedback of the click event. I have a Button style that has some style triggers associated and if i set the this style to the button all is OK. 
The problem is that many of the buttons have themselves different styles and i would like to use the triggers for all the buttons.

I have tried using the BasedOn property but im not seeing it as a StaticResources and as a dynamic resource i'm getting the following error.
A dynamic resources cannot be based on type style.

the code for the triggers is

```
<Style x:Key="BtnTriggerOnClick" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" Duration="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" />
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" Duration="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" />
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="120" CenterY="30" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

And one of the buttons i would like to appent this is

```
<Style x:Key="ClearButtonStyle" TargetType="Button"  >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B4B4B4" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,2" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#333333" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#777777" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Adding `BasedOn="{StaticResource BtnTriggerOnClick}"` to your `ClearButtonStyle` should work, assuming that `BtnTriggerOnClick` can be resolved from where `ClearButtonStyle` is declared. What exactly do you mean with 'I'm not seeing it as a static resource'? What errors do you get?

Comment: thanks for your help, yeah its really weird, i have them both in the same xaml file. When go to add as static resource intellisence doesn't have it, and when i manually type it in it says it cant be resolved. I have cleaned an rebuilt the project but still not finding it. Also there are no build errors when i build

Comment: Does it just say it can't find it, or does it actually error at runtime?

Comment: Remember that BtnTriggerOnClick must be before ClearButtonStyle...

Comment: Thanks guys, I am new to WPF and did not realize that the xaml is compiled in order, I had my style added to the end of the file so once i moved it to the start it all worked OK.